# Adding YouTube video to Bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I would like to add a YouTube video that pops up when clicking on the image.  Currently, the code displays a VIMEO video.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
    <ul id="grid" class="grid-wrapper">
        <li class="col-md-5 mix web"> <a href="img/portfolio/large/01.png" class="popup-image" title="Project Description"><div class="overlay"><span>Project Title</span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div><img src="img/portfolio/small/01.png" alt="" ></a> 
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-5 mix video"> <a href="#" class="popup-vimeo" title="Project Description"><div class="overlay"><span>Project Title</span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></div><img src="img/portfolio/small/02.jpg" alt="" ></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-5 mix branding"> <a href="img/portfolio/large/03.png" class="popup-image" title="Project Description"><div class="overlay"><span>Project Title</span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div><img src="img/portfolio/small/03.png" alt="" ></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-5 mix web"> <a href="img/portfolio/large/04.png" class="popup-image" title="Project Description"><div class="overlay"><span>Project Title</span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div><img src="img/portfolio/small/04.png" alt="" ></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-5 mix video"> <a href="#" class="popup-vimeo" title="Project Description"><div class="overlay"><span>Project Title</span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></div><img src="img/portfolio/small/05.png" alt="" ></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div (in display: none) which contains your URL YouTube and with jQuery you create an action (click()) that display it like that :

```
$(".myimage").click(function() {
    $("myvideo").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have something like <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/dKPE3/5/)**</kbd>, opening video in modal

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
    <ul id="grid" class="grid-wrapper">
        <li class="col-md-5 mix web"> <a href="img/portfolio/large/01.png" class="popup-image" title="Project Description"><div class="overlay"><span>Project Title</span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div><img src="img/portfolio/small/01.png" alt="" ></a> 
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-5 mix video"> <a href="#" class="popup-vimeo" title="Project Description"><div class="overlay"><span>Project Title</span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></div><img src="img/portfolio/small/02.jpg" alt="" ></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-5 mix branding"> <a href="img/portfolio/large/03.png" class="popup-image" title="Project Description"><div class="overlay"><span>Project Title</span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div><img src="img/portfolio/small/03.png" alt="" ></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-5 mix web"> <a href="img/portfolio/large/04.png" class="popup-image" title="Project Description"><div class="overlay"><span>Project Title</span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div><img src="img/portfolio/small/04.png" alt="" ></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-5 mix video"> <a href="#" class="popup-vimeo" title="Project Description"><div class="overlay"><span>Project Title</span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></div><img src="img/portfolio/small/05.png" alt="" ></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.video').click(function () {
    var src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0';
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModal iframe').attr('src', src);
});

$('#myModal button').click(function () {
    $('#myModal iframe').removeAttr('src');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="YoutubeButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">click here for video</div>                                      <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismihidden="true">&times;</button>
                <div class="modal-body">

                   <div class="videoWrapper">         
                      <iframe width="100%" height="450" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/the id of youtube video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                   </div>

               </div>

         </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Without having to write jquery

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals